# Image to PDF using pdfkit

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am facing issues while adding image to PDF.

```
result = """
    <h1>Image</h1>
    <img src="static/images/image.png">
    """
 
pdfkit.from_string(result, "static/images/foo.pdf")
```

Error:

```
raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: looks like it should work correctly..Ensure that the file path is accurate.

Comment: File path is correct

Answer (score 1):

Achieved by decoding the image,

```
import base64

filepath = "static/images/Image.png"
binary_fc       = open(filepath, 'rb').read()  # fc aka file_content
base64_utf8_str = base64.b64encode(binary_fc).decode('utf-8')

ext     = filepath.split('.')[-1]
dataurl = f'data:image/{ext};base64,{base64_utf8_str}'

result = """
    <img src= """  + dataurl + """>
    """
pdfkit.from_string(result, "static/images/foo.pdf")
```